# Can I use Watson Text to Speech in videos?

Tags: watson-text-to-speech

I'm looking for a text to speech solution to use in commercial and technical videos.

I've tried the Watson Text to Speech demo and it looks great.

However, I'm not looking to use it within an application but only to add speech in commercial and technical videos for our products.

Is that in any way allowed and if so, how can I purchase and use the solution ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the license it was shipped with?  It should tell you if there are any usage restrictions in there.

Comment: Watson Text to speech is a iBM cloud based solution that appears to be only used to be implemented in applications. It has a default "Lite" registration with 10.000 characters per months and then it's 0.02$ per thouthand words. However, as I said I'm not interested in using it in an app. Just in videos. Can't find any contacts with IBM or any documentation to help me...

Comment: That's a description.  When you got the demo, there should be a licence file that came with it.

Comment: There is a "Therms of use" page for the demo that states "The Application is not intended to be used for productive or commercial purposes, and such use is not permitted." but I can't find anywhere how I can use the product for my videos and pay for it. No support available either...

Comment: Then choose something else.  If IBM doesn't want let you do interesting things with their product, then choose someone else.